# options[1][APPLICATION_COMMAND_OPTIONS_REQUIRED_INVALID]: Required options must be placed before non-required options

Tags: javascript

When using the node src/register-commands.js command in VSC the options1 application command options required shows as invalid the required options must be placed before non required options

```
const commands = [
    {
        name: 'add',
        description: 'Adds two numbers', 
        options: [
{
   name: 'first-number', 
   description: 'The first number' , 
   type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Number,
   choices:  [
    {
        name: 'one',
        value:1,
        },
        {
            name: 'two',
            value:2,

        },
        {
            name: 'three',
            value:3,

        }
   ]
},
{
    name: 'second-number', 
    description: 'The second number.', 
    type:ApplicationCommandOptionType.Number,
    required: true,
},
```